# Is there a way I can write about how this website has benefitted in my music learning journey?

Tags: discussion

This question itself may sound silly, but it's more of my experience here over the last 1 year that I've been a member. I attempted to give my Music Theory Exam last year  through self-study, and I passed my exam. I want to appreciate all the people who took time to answer my questions and commented on them. I learnt a lot of my work through this website.

I thought this would be a small way of acknowledging this website. It's a great platform to learn about music. And I hope many people like me are able to benefit.

If such a post is against the website guidelines, please let me know, and I'll take it down.

Comment: That's good news, Grace! Well done!

Comment: Thanks @OldBrixtonian

Answer (score 10):

Congratulations, Grace! It's lovely to hear that.

I always encourage Music students to come here - this site won't give you everything (technique, for example, is very difficult to explain without being there in person) but there are a lot of very experienced people who are glad to help.

It's been far too many years since I did formal learning in Music, but this site has been helping me learn some of the theory I should have got years ago.

I hope your musical journey continues and you keep on learning and enjoying it!

Comment: Absolutely, this site has a lot of experienced people sharing their opinions...and what a better way to learn than from each other!